# Локализация PhoneGap приложения

Tags: phonegap, android, ios, javascript

Здравствуйте! Как можно локализовать приложение на этой платформе? У меня была идея создать файл и в нем писать текст, вызывать нужные строки парсингом из файла или например json парсером. Так это делается или нет?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PhoneGap Android String Plugin: http://code.google.com/p/pgandroidstring/

Answer (score 1):

С phonegap почти не работал, но вроде бы он хранит все свое в виде ресурсов, а значит должен по идее починиться обычному для айоси способу локализации через создание папок ru.lproj, en.lproj и т.д.